# Inner join a single row by getting only the highest integer row

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

When I inner join the second table I only want to join a single row. The criteria is to take the row with the highest integer in the level column. I was thinking something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM file_repo
INNER JOIN
(   SELECT 
       MAX(files.level)
    FROM
       files
) ON file_repo.id = files.repo_id
```

For each row in file_repo I will get a single row from files with the highest value in the level column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    file_repo fr
JOIN    files f
ON      f.id = 
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    files fi
        WHERE   fi.repo_id = fr.id
        ORDER BY
                repo_id DESC, level DESC, id DESC
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

Create an index on `files (repo_id, level, id)` for this to work fast.

This will handle duplicates on `level` correctly.

Comment: This solution seems to run rather slowly compared with the other one (10x or so).  What is the problem that occurs when two file_repo's share the same level in the other example?  Is it just inconsistent choice of matching file?

Comment: @ebyrob: you will get all latest files instead of one. Note that performance depends on how the tables are indexed, and the other solution can be faster indeed if you have lots of empty repos (with no files at all).

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT fr.*, fm.MaxLevel
FROM file_repo fr
INNER JOIN (   
    SELECT repo_id, MAX(level) as MaxLevel
    FROM files 
    GROUP BY repo_id
) fm ON fr.id = fm.repo_id
```